# VS Code: display *.js-meta.xml files in the Explorer

Tags: vs-code

In VS Code, I frequently need to update `*.js-meta.xml` files used with Lightning Web Components.  By default, VS Code does not display these files in the Explorer for my Salesforce project.  Is there a setting in VS Code (or the Salesforce Extension Pack) that will display these files in the Explorer?

Comment: I can see all my `*.js-meta.xml` files.  Have you tried searching for "exclude" in your VS Code settings to see if you have some type of exclusion criteria in place there?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29965939/how-to-hide-files-with-specific-extension-in-vscode-tree-view

Comment: @MatthewSouther that was exactly the issue.  I had added that user setting a year ago, and completely forgot about it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the VSCode Settings, (either in workspace or user) you might have something like `**/*-meta.xml` in your `Files: Exclude` section

you should change that to specify the ones you really want to hide, for example `**/*.cls-meta.xml`.

Have a look also to the `Search: Exclude` section

Comment: I had changed the files: exclude setting to include that pattern.  For me, it made sense to do this because I hadn't been working with LWC components until now.  Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

*.js-meta.xml files are getting created along with component whenever we are creating it.

Until and unless we are hiding certain files as stated by Mathew Souther , these will be visible by default.

Also, pleas try to refresh your folder after creating component. I have seen instances when this file comes after folder refresh in VS-Code